# Give port number and passed parameters in WSO2

Tags: java, api, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I am trying to learn WSO2 but have been stuck at a minor step which i believe should be quite easy to do. While creating a new api i need to give the production endpoint. What i want to give is the url along with the port as well. So it should be something like this: 
Production Endpoint : http://localhost:9000
However this gives a invalid url. How can i specify port along with it. Please help. I have tried to go through the docs but could not find anything. I am doing these through the admin UI available at http://myip:9443/publisher.
Please advice

Edit: Adding image for clarity[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Test button will send HTTP OPTION request to the endpoint, and if the endpoint supports HTTP OPTION request, then it will be shown as Valid, otherwise, it will be shown as Invalid

As far as your backend point support the HTTP method you need, you don't need to worry about this Test button against the endpoint.

Comment: oh...so that means that in the endpoint i can add something like http://localhost:9000 ?

Comment: Yes, you can add, but that endpoint should support the HTTP Method you have added through API Definition. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Create+and+Publish+an+API